# WPF Application is deadlocked when invoking on the Dispatcher

Tags: wpf, deadlock, dispatcher

We are occasionally having a situation where the application is deadlocked and it seems that the dispatcher is deadlocked with a background thread trying to invoke on the dispatcher. I don't see that either thread has any shared resources that are locked. The background thread has encountered an exception and it ends up at the app domain unhandled exception delegate because no one picked up this exception. This calls our exception handler that is tasked with insuring that our exception dialog is put onto the dispatcher.

Can someone suggest ways that I can figure out what is causing the deadlock?

The dispatcher stack follows and doesn't look out of the ordinary:

```
*0. System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait (source line information unavailable)

 1. System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.InvokeWaitMethodHelper (source line information unavailable)
 2. Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DeferredOperationManager.Process (source line information unavailable)
 3. Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DeferredOperationManager.Dispatched_Process (source line information unavailable)
 4. System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (source line information unavailable)
 5. System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen (source line information unavailable)
 6. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke (source line information unavailable)
 7. System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl (source line information unavailable)
 8. System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext (source line information unavailable)
 9. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode (source line information unavailable)
 10. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (source line information unavailable)
 11. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (source line information unavailable)
 12. System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke (source line information unavailable)
 13. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue (source line information unavailable
 14. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook (source line information unavailable)
 15. MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc (source line information unavailable)
 16. MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation (source line information unavailable)
 17. System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (source line information unavailable)
 18. System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen (source line information unavailable)
 19. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke (source line information unavailable)
 20. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl (source line information unavailable)
 21. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke (source line information unavailable)
 22. MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc (source line information unavailable)
    [Internal Frame, 'M-->U']
 23. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl (source line information unavailable)
 24. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame (source line information unavailable)
 25. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run (source line information unavailable)
 26. System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher (source line information unavailable)
 27. System.Windows.Application.RunInternal (source line information unavailable)
 28. System.Windows.Application.Run (source line information unavailable)
 29. System.Windows.Application.Run (source line information unavailable)
 30. Wmc.Gtseq.Client.Desktop.App.Main (source line information unavailable)
```

The second threads stack starts bascically from the app domain unhandled exception handler:

```
*0. System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (source line information unavailable)

 1. System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (source line information unavailable)
 2. System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation+DispatcherOperationEvent.WaitOne (source line information unavailable)
 3. System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait (source line information unavailable)
 4. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl (source line information unavailable)
 5. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke (source line information unavailable)
 6. Wmc.Gtseq.Core.ForwardPort.Extensions.DispatcherExtension.InvokeIfRequired (source line information unavailable)
 7. Wmc.Gtseq.Core.ForwardPort.Utilities.DispatcherHelper.InvokeOnMainThread (source line information unavailable)
 8. Wmc.Gtseq.Core.ForwardPort.Handlers.ExceptionHandler.ThreadSafeDialogHandler (source line information unavailable)
 9. Wmc.Gtseq.Core.ForwardPort.Handlers.ExceptionHandler.ShowErrorDialog (source line information unavailable)
 10. Wmc.Gtseq.Core.ForwardPort.Handlers.ExceptionHandler.HandleException (source line information unavailable)
 11. Wmc.Gtseq.Client.Desktop.App.AppDomainUnhandledException (source line information unavailable)
```

It appears that the Invoke is waiting as expected but also appears that the dispatcher thread itself is blocked. We have waited for many minutes in these situations and the application never comes back. Any help or insight would be appreciated. I know I can switch to BeginInvoke but based on the context here I worry that my background thread would continue and that the UI would either be blocked for the same reason or the exception dialog would not appear.

Our background thread executes the following code flow when the exception shows up at the domain unhandled exception handler:

```
protected override void AppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionHandler.HandleException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception, false);
    }

public static void HandleException(Exception ex, bool closeApp)
    {
        ThreadSafeDialogHandler((Action)delegate { ErrorDialog.ShowDialog(ex, closeApp); });           
    }

private static void ThreadSafeDialogHandler(Action methodCall)
    {
        DispatcherHelper.InvokeOnMainThread(() => { methodCall(); });
    }

public static void InvokeOnMainThread(Action method)
    {
        Application.Current.InvokeIfRequired(method, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    }

public static void InvokeIfRequired(this DispatcherObject control, Action methodcall, DispatcherPriority priorityForCall)
    {
        // see if we need to Invoke call to Dispatcher thread  
        if (control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            methodcall();
        }
        else
        {
            control.Dispatcher.Invoke(priorityForCall, methodcall);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I posted the code that executes starting from the app domain unhandled exception handler.

Comment: It would be more interesting to see the stack trace of the UI thread while the deadlock is active. The UI thread is probably waiting for something so the dispatcher gets blocked. Break the debugger next time the deadlock happens and check the stack trace of the UI thread. Could it be that your UI thread is in a Thread.Join (or something similar) while your background thread tries to Invoke on the dispatcher? I stopped using Invoke a long time ago because of deadlocks.. only BeginInvoke.

Comment: My ui thread is posted above. It is the first stack displayed. With Invoke vs. BeginInvoke, my understanding is that Invoke ends up calling Begin lower down but also has the handling to wait. Is this not true? Does Invoke attempt to directly interrupt the thread while BeginInvoke posts to the queue?

Comment: I think you should put a try catch around      ThreadSafeDialogHandler((Action)delegate { ErrorDialog.ShowDialog(ex, closeApp); }); because if there is an exception handling the exception it will be an unhandled exception if you manually handle it you don't get in a loop

Comment: @Ben. Did you ever get a resolution to this issue? I am getting it also and using Invoke or BeginInvoke doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Jim - I don't recall to be honest. Many things happened since then. Two points though. 1. The unhandled exception was being triggered because a third party component was spawning its own thread and that thread was throwing an exception. We couldn't capture it so it ended up at the app domain. 2. We have since changed the code and are only calling Application.Current.InvokeIfRequired. Presumably one of these addressed the issue. I wish I had more concrete information.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `control.Dispatcher.Invoke` try `control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, that has helped me before in such corner cases.

Also, your code seems a bit strange to me. In my app, I set the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event handler in the main window `Loaded()` event. The event is attached to a local method of the main window. As such I don't need to do any Dispatcher invoking, because the event is already raised on the main dispatcher thread, even if the error does happen on another thread altogether.

Comment: It's not always possible to just switch from `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke`. The former is synchronous, and the latter is asynchronous. If the callee depends on the effects of the invoked call, it might be that easy.